# Adding ID attributes to content in tag wikis?

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki, information-display

A lot of focus has been rising for tag wikis lately, which is good, yes. However, if we are expected to put so much information into the tag wikis, shouldn't we also have some easy way to direct users to specific content within that tag wiki, rather than just saying "read through such and such tag wiki"?

For example, what if I wanted to direct a user to the specific FAQ answer for "Headers already sent by..." in the [PHP tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info). It's a ways down on the page, not particularly in any good position. Sure, I could say it's the third question under the FAQ, but it would be a lot simpler if I could just type in a unique identifier for it to quickly and automatically direct the user to that specific section, rather than making them search for it. Example:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info#headers-already-sent
```

Attempting to manually set the ID via `<dt id="headers-already-sent">` or `<a name="headers-already-sent"></a>` causes the element to be removed by the HTML cleanser. Can we get this enabled, or possibly add a way to add anchors which only contain an ID attribute, for quick jumping to a specific place on the page?

Comment: A lazy md5 auto-generated hash slapped on all headers perhaps?

Comment: Doing it for headers seems sensible to me (as would captioned items, if they were supported). Documents where you link to anything else tend to suck in usability/readability terms.

Comment: I support this, let me have think

Comment: @waffles Did you finish thinking yet? I support this 100%. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132412/164367

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would make sense if you were to make headings in a tag wiki auto-generate an ID that wouldn't conflict with any of the page elements.

Headings denote sections in a logical fashion and would be a better way to jump-link to.

This heading:

```
##Breaking backs on mountains
```

Could have an auto-generated ID like:

```
<h2 id="#tw-breaking-backs-on-mountains">Breaking backs on mountains</h2>
```

Comment: I like this solution, very elegant.