# Allow named anchors in tag wikis

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding ID attributes to content in tag wikis?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122130/adding-id-attributes-to-content-in-tag-wikis)

I have seen this requested before for posts, [Support anchor names in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37894/164367), but couldn't find one for tag wikis.

With the on going drive to make tag wikis more useful and relevant I hope that they will be linked to more often. I spend most of my time in the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag which does have a pretty [comprehensive wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info). I think that this is a resource that we (I) do not use enough and realise that there are many questions by new users that could usefully be referred to the tag wiki.

It would be an even more useful resource if we were able to link directly to the relevant part of the wiki such as one of the FAQ's, in this case, for example, I think the FAQ about "does not work" will be particularly useful (*it would have been nice to be able to link directly to it here*).

Would it be possible to allow named anchors to be created in tag wikis? I think it would be simpler to implement than for posts and potentially much more useful.

Comment: @animuson I didn't find that one. Probably because I searched for 'name' and not ID. I added my close vote to this.

Comment: I figured. I only knew about it because I wrote it... :P

Comment: No harm in asking again, hopefully it will eventually get implemented.